# CNTK: ValueError unbound Placeholder found in the function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cntk

I am working on CNTK and got following error:

> **ValueError**: 2 unbound Placeholder(s) 'Placeholder('keep', [#, *], [939]), Placeholder('keep', [#, *], [939])' found in the Function. All Placeholders of a Function must be bound (to a variable) before performing a Forward computation.

```
for i in range(10000):
    a1,a2,tar=get_sample(minibatch_size,start)
    start=start+int(minibatch_size)
    if start>=int(0.8*float(len(lab)))-minibatch_size:
       start=0
    trainer.train_minibatch({P1: a1, P2: a2, target: tar})
```

> P1 and P2 are defined as C.layers.Input(939)

Comment: I get a similar error : ValueError: 1 unbound Placeholder(s) 'Placeholder('keep', [???], [???])' found in the Function. I am unable to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problem in my case. I had to pass the model output instead of the model itself as a parameter to the trainer constructor.

model = cntk.layers.Sequential([l1,l2])

model_output = model(predictor)

Error:
trainer = cntk.train.trainer.Trainer(model,(loss,meas),[learner])

No Error:
trainer = cntk.train.trainer.Trainer(model_output,(loss,meas),[learner])